# How to create custom email headers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sendgrid

I'm trying to create a custom email header to use the SendGrid api.

Here's what I'm doing - but its not working:

```
class Mailman < ActionMailer::Base
  default :from => "info@sample.com"

  def send_message(name, email, message)
    @name = name
    @email = email
    @message = message

    mail(:to => 'info@sample.com',
     :from => email,
     :subject => "Message from the site",
     :headers['X-SMTPAPI'] => "category: Drip Email"
    )
  end

end
```

Any help appreciated.

Thanks,
Adam

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can use the #headers method of ActionMailer, I've edited your example to show how:

```
class Mailman < ActionMailer::Base
  default :from => "info@sample.com"

  def send_message(name, email, message)
    @name = name
    @email = email
    @message = message

    headers['X-SMTPAPI'] = '{"category": "Drip Email"}'

    mail(
     :to => 'info@sample.com',
     :from => email,
     :subject => "Message from the site"
    )
  end

end
```

Alternatively, you can pass a hash as an argument (to the method #headers) too:

```
headers {"SPECIFIC-HEADER-1" => "value", "ANOTHER-HEADER" => "and so..."}
```

I hope this can help you, and if not you always can check the rails guides: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html.

Comment: Thanks Ricardo - the answer was in front of my face.  I had tried this and got it working.  Then you posted which confirmed my solution.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

I am using below code and works fine, just convert the hash to json with `to_json`

```
headers['X-SMTPAPI'] = { 
  category: "Weekly Newsletter",
  unique_args: { user_id: user.id } 
}.to_json
```

Answer (score 3):

To use the unsubscribe groups in the suppression group functionality within sendgrid, I used the following syntax which worked.

```
headers['X-SMTPAPI'] = '{"asm_group_id": 1111}'
```

Answer (score 2):

The headers method requires valid JSON. So Ricardo's solution requires this line instead:

```
headers['X-SMTPAPI'] = '{"category": "Drip Email"}'
```