# SendGrid vs ActionMailer vs mail server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, sendgrid

I am building a Rails application with the following functionality: when receiving emails from users, parse the content, perform some tasks and send update emails to users, with low latency.

For receiving emails, I have MailMan gem. For sending email, I have ActionMailer. For mail server, I am using Gmail with Pop3.

It seems that SendGrid is a popular thing for email. I have a hard time understanding what exactly SendGrid does beyond ActionMailer. Is SendGrid an SMTP email server and an alternative to my Gmail Pop3? Does it handle incoming emails?

What are the advantages over ActionMailer?

Answer (score 12):

I work at SendGrid.

SendGrid is primarily for SMTP (outbound) email. You can read an overview explaining what SendGrid does [here](http://sendgrid.com/docs/User_Guide/index.html). The advantages of using SendGrid are better deliverability (less likely to go to spam folder), scalability, analytics, and access to APIs for doing more complex things like associating unique arguments with individual emails. We do have an [Inbound Parse webhook](http://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Webhooks/parse.html) that will help you parse inbound emails without the need for storing those messages in a mailbox. We do not offer any mailboxes (POP3/IMAP) or any message storage capabilities.

SendGrid and ActionMailer are complimentary. You can [use SendGrid with ActionMailer](http://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Frameworks/rubyonrails.html) as described in our docs.

You don't mention if you are using gmail as an SMTP server to send your app's messages, but if you do, there are some limitations such as the number of emails you can send per day.

Let me know if I can answer any more questions for you. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot, Brand. Just to be sure I understand the product: it is a SMTP server. If I use it, my emails will be sent out from SendGrid server instead of my GMail server. There're some benefits by doing this b/c you guys ensure that I follow anti-spam rules.

Comment: Yep, you've got the basics of it. Not just anti-spam rules; we handle things like DKIM and SPF that make your emails more trusted by recipients and less likely to be seen as spam. There are also features like click tracking, subscription management, substitution templates, etc.

Comment: @bwest hi, i'm at the stage where I'm implemented payments with Stripe and I need to send emails to the purchaser. I signed up for Sendgrid and I'm curious if I can use SendGrid templates with Rails?  I'm looking at the docs you suggested and they mention a gem for advances features, but that them hasn't been updated in two years.

Comment: @batman yep, you can add [custom headers via ActionMailer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7012203/how-to-create-custom-email-headers) - so you can add a `X-SMTPAPI` header with the `templates` filter enable a `template_id`, as shown in [the docs](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Template_Engine/smtpapi.html)